# How to manage issue while converting character to factor in R

Tags: r

I have this data:

```
years <- c("2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", "2016", "2017", 
"2018", "2019", "2020")

n_cohorts <- length(years)

df <- structure(list(label2plot = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L
), levels = c("aaa", "bbb"), class = c("ordered", 
"factor")), var_abs = c(717L, 569L, 860L, 752L, 713L, 575L, 918L, 
724L, 946L, 764L, 951L, 764L, 784L, 691L, 672L, 610L, 833L, 671L, 
773L, 620L, 532L, 293L), var_rel = c(0.557542768273717, 0.442457231726283, 
0.533498759305211, 0.466501240694789, 0.553571428571429, 0.446428571428571, 
0.559074299634592, 0.440925700365408, 0.553216374269006, 0.446783625730994, 
0.554518950437318, 0.445481049562682, 0.531525423728814, 0.468474576271186, 
0.52418096723869, 0.47581903276131, 0.553856382978723, 0.446143617021277, 
0.554917444364681, 0.445082555635319, 0.644848484848485, 0.355151515151515
), year = c("2020", "2020", "2019", "2019", "2018", "2018", 
"2017", "2017", "2016", "2016", "2015", "2015", "2014", "2014", 
"2013", "2013", "2012", "2012", "2011", "2011", "2010", "2010"
)), row.names = c(NA, -22L), class = "data.frame")

cohorts <- length(years)
```

I would like to convert `year` into a factor. I proceed as follows:

```
df$year2  <- factor(df$year,
                    levels = c(1:n_cohorts),
                    labels = years)
```

I get the following result and cannot explain why `NA`s appear in `year2`. Does anyone have an idea what I am doing wrong?

```
structure(list(label2plot = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L
), levels = c("aaa", "bbb"), class = c("ordered", "factor")), 
    var_abs = c(717L, 569L, 860L, 752L, 713L, 575L, 918L, 724L, 
    946L, 764L, 951L, 764L, 784L, 691L, 672L, 610L, 833L, 671L, 
    773L, 620L, 532L, 293L), var_rel = c(0.557542768273717, 0.442457231726283, 
    0.533498759305211, 0.466501240694789, 0.553571428571429, 
    0.446428571428571, 0.559074299634592, 0.440925700365408, 
    0.553216374269006, 0.446783625730994, 0.554518950437318, 
    0.445481049562682, 0.531525423728814, 0.468474576271186, 
    0.52418096723869, 0.47581903276131, 0.553856382978723, 0.446143617021277, 
    0.554917444364681, 0.445082555635319, 0.644848484848485, 
    0.355151515151515), year = c("2020", "2020", "2019", "2019", 
    "2018", "2018", "2017", "2017", "2016", "2016", "2015", "2015", 
    "2014", "2014", "2013", "2013", "2012", "2012", "2011", "2011", 
    "2010", "2010"), year2 = structure(c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_
    ), levels = c("2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", 
    "2016", "2017", "2018", "2019", "2020"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-22L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: What is your expected results? Do you want to replace 2010 by 1, 2011 by 2, etc.? In that case you need to switch the levels and labels arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`levels=` is

```
  levels: an optional vector of the unique values (as character
          strings) that 'x' might have taken.  The default is the
          unique set of values taken by 'as.character(x)', sorted into
          increasing order _of 'x'_.  Note that this set can be
          specified as smaller than 'sort(unique(x))'.
```

which means that it should include `"2020"`, etc. You are trying to pass it integers 1 through 11, which do not appear. Because your real `df$year` values are not found in `1:11`, they are all converted to `NA`.

```r
factor(df$year, levels = 1:n_cohorts, labels = years)
#  [1] <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
# Levels: 2010 2011 2012 2013 2014 2015 2016 2017 2018 2019 2020
```

Drop the `levels=` and/or change `labels=` to `levels=`.

```r
factor(df$year, labels = years)
#  [1] 2020 2020 2019 2019 2018 2018 2017 2017 2016 2016 2015 2015 2014 2014 2013 2013 2012 2012 2011 2011 2010 2010
# Levels: 2010 2011 2012 2013 2014 2015 2016 2017 2018 2019 2020

factor(df$year, levels = years)
#  [1] 2020 2020 2019 2019 2018 2018 2017 2017 2016 2016 2015 2015 2014 2014 2013 2013 2012 2012 2011 2011 2010 2010
# Levels: 2010 2011 2012 2013 2014 2015 2016 2017 2018 2019 2020
```

(They are identical.)